# How to create simple login in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-oauth2

Based on the SCDF document, as of Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.0, OAuth2 is the only mechanism for providing authentication and authorization.
However, I want to create the simple login page without using Authentication provider. Could I apply Spring Boot Security following this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) to Spring Cloud Data Flow project?

I have also tried the example using UAA and LDAP server [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example). But I am looking for the more simple way for authorization.

Comment: I have been looking for one for sometime now. But apart from the UAA and other Oauth mechanism they don't have any it seems. Would you be able to find any workaround?